# c++ Start process with argument

Tags: c++, forms, process, arguments

i know how to Start process with argument but im trying to create a program that uses this arguments. for example IE8 uses Process::Start( "IExplore.exe","google.com"); as a argument to open new window with url google.com. i want my program to use the argument are send it but i don't know how to get the the argument. like Process::Start( "myprogram.exe","TURE"); i want my program to get the ture
thanks in advance 
Rami

Comment: Do you have an introductory C++ book?  If you do, this is probably covered in one of the very first chapters.  If you don't, you should consider getting one of the introductory books listed in [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you write your entry point something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Then `argc` is the number of arguments used to invoke your program and `argv` are the actual arguments.

Try it out:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
}
```

Comment: If you're using the Windows entry point: `int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)`, then `lpCmdLine` is the command line and `nCmdShow` is the number of arguments.

Answer (score 4):

There are two choices, depending on what kind of program you are building.

- If your program is a console mode program, use `argc` and `argv` parameters passed to your `main()`.
- If your program is a GUI mode program, use the `pCmdLine` parameter passed to your [`WinMain()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381406(VS.85).aspx).

In either case, you can always use [`GetCommandLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: GetCommandLine() is windows-specific though and not portable, so using argc/argv is usually to be preferred.

Comment: That's correct. I thought it was pretty clear that the OP is using Windows.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
system("IExplore.exe google.com");
```